# Why the extract function stopped extracting?

Tags: python, function, extract

Can someone explain and help me resolve why my function stopped extracting .tgz files when I added a counter to create folders with different names to keep the extracted folder from overwriting the previous one when I extracted another .tgz file in the same directory? What am I doing wrong? Thanks! Below are the two functions ... the first function extracts files properly; the second function extracts a numbered folder and quits.

Works:

```
 def extract(tar_url, extract_path='.'):
        print tar_url
        tar = tarfile.open(tar_url, 'r')
        for item in tar:
            tar.extract(item, extract_path)
            if item.name.find(".tgz") != -1 or item.name.find(".tar") != -1:
               extract(item.name, "./" + item.name[:item.name.rfind('/')])
```

Does not work:

```
 global counter
 counter=1

 def extract(tar_url, extract_path='.'):
      global counter
      print tar_url
      tar = tarfile.open(tar_url, 'wb')# changed from r to wb 6/12
      for item in tar:
          tar.extract(item, extract_path+"_%d"%counter) 
          counter+=1
          if item.name.find(".tgz") != -1 or item.name.find(".tar") != -1:
              extract(item.name, "./" + item.name[:item.name.rfind('/')])
```

Here is how I call it in main (I'm using easygui):

```
  direct = diropenbox(msg="Choose path to place extracted files!", title='SQA Extractor', default='c:\\Extracted')          
  msg = "Are you sure you want to extract?"
  title = "Confirm"
  os.chdir(direct)      

  try:
           for root, dirname, files in os.walk(directory):
                for file1 in files:
                     if file1.endswith(".tgz") or file1.endswith(".tar"):
                         extract(os.path.join(root, file1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it was this change that broke your code:

```
tar = tarfile.open(tar_url, 'r')
```

Changed to:

```
tar = tarfile.open(tar_url, 'wb')# changed from r to wb 6/12
```

Comment: I did that after it was already broken, hoping to fix it, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Does the extract path with the counter exist?

```
  for item in tar:
      os.mkdir(extract_path + "_%d" % counter)
      tar.extract(item, extract_path+"_%d" % counter)
      counter+=1
      if item.name.find(".tgz") != -1 or item.name.find(".tar") != -1:
          extract(item.name, "./" + item.name[:item.name.rfind('/')])
```

Answer (score 0):

The original version relies on the created folder names matching the relative paths specified in the archive. In the new version, the recursive call tries to put the files into a folder without a 'tag' number, after extracting the other files at that level into one that does.

Try adding the tag to the path name used for the recursive call as well.

BTW, the Python-idiomatic spelling of `item.name.find(".tar") != -1` is `'.tar' in item.name`.

Comment: are you saying to add the path to the function call in main: extract(os.path.join(root, file1))?

Comment: No, just the **tag**. `extract(item.name, "./" + item.name[:item.name.rfind('/')] + "_%d" % counter)`

Comment: The behavior is still the same, but it does not even create the numbered folder now.